# Using OMPL with turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My intention in to implement an algorithm for path planning to Turtlebot. I'd like to implement the RRT (Rapidly-exploring Random Tree) planner using OMPL Library.
Is it possible? or discouraged me to do this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113111/using-ompl-with-turtlebot/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Please take a look at the list of planners already implemented in OMPL:
http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/planners.html

RRT is already part of OMPL, so I think you need not bother re-implementing it.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-03-20**:
Do you know if there is any package in Hydro that allows to use OMPL planner? I'd like to navigate Turtlebot with a RRT planner.